# get all keys from json column and convert to rows

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I have a table like the following, where cities is a `JSON` column

| ID | cities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["madrid"] |
| 2 | ["london", "madrid", "paris"] |
| 3 | ["london", "paris"] |
| 4 | ["london"] |
| 5 | ["rome", "berlin"] |

I would like to convert that column to rows, where all individual city gets its own row

| city |
| --- |
| madrid |
| london |
| paris |
| rome |
| berlin |

I've tried something like

```
SELECT distinct JSON_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT(cities, '$[*]'), '$[*]') as cities FROM table_cities
```

but I get this instead

| city |
| --- |
| madrid |
| NULL |
| london |

Comment: try `JSON_TABLE`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table

Comment: What is precise DBMS version? show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina I can use both MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using MySQL version 8.0, you can try using the function `JSON_TABLE` (tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=939d5180323f97b316dc65f3d617d905))

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.city
FROM table_cities c,
JSON_TABLE(
  c.cities,
  '$[*]'
  COLUMNS(
  city VARCHAR(10) PATH '$[0]'
  )
) tmp;
```

2. For MariaDB 10.4.2, you can try this. (tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c3b6879e7cb8ad7ff40a3fa3b46e93c2))

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    cities VARCHAR(1000)
);

-- create procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1()
BEGIN
SET @index := 0;
SELECT @json_length := MAX(JSON_LENGTH(cities))
FROM table_cities;

REPEAT
   INSERT INTO main_table (cities)
   SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(cities,CONCAT("$[",@index,"]")) FROM table_cities;
   SET @index = @index + 1;
UNTIL @index = @json_length 
END REPEAT;
END;

-- call procedure
CALL proc1;

-- query result
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(cities, '"', '') AS city 
FROM main_table
WHERE cities IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you. Do you know how to achieve the same thing with MariaDB 10.4.2? I don't know If could upgrade to 10.6

Comment: @MatíasCánepa I have added a solution (point no.2) , let me know if this works for you.